# Emitting a hot boolean observable using switchMap?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, switchmap

Trying to create an `isEmpty:Observable<boolean>`method that emits a hot `Observable<boolean>` using a `switchMap`.  This is what I have so far:

```
  /**
   * Notifies observers when the store is empty.
   */
  protected notifyOnEmpty = new ReplaySubject<E[]>(1);

  /**
   * Check whether the store is empty.
   * 
   * @return A hot {@link Observable<boolean>} that indicates whether the store is empty.
   * 
   * @example
     <pre>
    source.isEmpty();
    </pre>
  */
  isEmpty<E>():Observable<boolean> {
    const isCurrentlyEmpty = values(this.entries).length == 0;
    return this.notifyOnEmpty.pipe(startWith(isCurrentlyEmpty), 
                                   switchMap((entries:E[])=>entries.length == 0));
  }
```

The thinking is that the store can then call `notifyOnEmpty.next(Object.values(this.entries))` to let subscribers know whether the store is empty.

Anyways the switchMap statement leads to the error:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '(entries: E[]) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: E[], index: number) => ObservableInput'.
>     Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
>   (parameter) entries: E[]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switchMap` operator is used to select a new observable on each value. You only need a regular `map` so that each `Array` is mapped to a `boolean`:

```
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

isEmpty<E>():Observable<boolean> {
  return this.notifyOnEmpty.pipe(
    startWith(values(this.entries)), 
    map((entries:E[]) => entries.length == 0)
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks that makes a lot more sense :).  I'm getting a different error now: [ts]
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<E[], boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<boolean | E[], boolean>'.
  Type 'boolean | E[]' is not assignable to type 'E[]'.
    Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'E[]'.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to do `startWith(values(this.entries))` instead. That way `map` is always mapping `E[]` items. As it currently is, you're starting with a boolean, which is why the type `boolean | E[]` instead of `E[]`.

Comment: OK COOL!  I ended up nuking the startWith, since the `entries` will have length zero by default on startup.  Thanks again!

Comment: Slice stores now have observable count and empty notification: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/slice